# REST API error: Primary key '(primarykey)' does not exists

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, dataextensions, marketingcloudapi

I am trying to upsert a row into a triggered send data extension with a synchronous call, but I am receiving the following error message:

```
{
    "message": "Primary key 'Email' does not exist.",
    "errorcode": 10000,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

My api call is as follows:

```
Host: https://my_sub_domain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com 
POST /hub/v1/dataevents/DE_external_key/rowset 
Content-Type: application/json 
Authorization: Bearer my_access_token
[
    {
        "keys":{
                "Email": "willem.ruys@domain.com"
                },
        "values":{
                "Language": "en",
                "Country": "NL"
                }
    }
]
```

DE attributes are:

```
PK? yes - Name: Email - type: Email - length: 254 - Nullable? No
PK? No - Name: Language - type: text - Length: 50 - Nullable? No
PK? No - Name: Country - type: text - Length: 50 - Nullable? No
```

I find it strange that my error code says that thee Primary Key 'Email' does not exist. Anyone who has a solution perhaps?

Thanks

Comment: Is the External Key of your target data extension really `DE_external_key`?

Comment: Hi Adam, no it's not - I just put `DE_external_key` as a placeholder.

Answer (score 7):

In the `POST` you're missing `key:` before your DE's External Key, so it should be like this :

```
POST /hub/v1/dataevents/key:DE_external_key/rowset
```

Comment: Thanks Zak, this solved the problem indeed.